# jquery datatables server side process with external form

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

We have more than 200 000 records. Datatables take too much time to load.

here is code we have using

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dataTable = $('#dataTables-example').DataTable( {
        responsive: true,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        'iDisplayLength': 25,
        "aaSorting": [[ 7, "desc" ]],
        "ajax": $.fn.dataTable.pipeline( {
            url: 'report_list_ajax.php'
        }),
        "columnDefs": [ 
            {"targets": 0, "orderable": false },
            {"targets": 4, "orderable": false },
        ]
    });
});
```

so we dont need jquery datatables load or initialize while page loading.

and jquery datatables initialize and execute when submitted the external form only.

i.e: "FROM" and "TO Date" selection and click on submit button, the datatables will load based on form inputs..

Comment: Please fix the text after the code. It is really hard to understand. For example "we need datatables won't load" doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Datatables initialize and execute when external form submit:

```
$("#external_form_id").on("submit", function(){
    //datatable initiate code...
});
```

Based on code above, datatable will not initiate until the external form trigger submit. This is what u want?

Comment: at the same time i need send form input value too

Comment: Try this to parse in your data into datatable initiate code:
"sAjaxSource": //url,
"sServerMethod": "POST",
"fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
  aoData.push({ "name": "action", "value": "anything" });
},